# Importing CSV to Jupyter Notebook on Mac (python)

Tags: python, macos, csv, import, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to import a csv file from my desktop to my jupyter notebook and then open and read it. I made sure to save the csv file in the same folder as the ipynb file.

here is the code I've used so far:

```
%matplotlib inline

import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
```

```
userhome = os.path.expanduser('~')
csvfile= userhome + r'/Desktop/Software/evil_corp.csv'
open(csvfile, "r")
```

and this is the response I'm getting:

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='/Users/jessicanicholson/Desktop/Software/evil_corp.csv' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>
```

how do i proceed from here? I thought the last request would open/ view the file.

Comment: Try following a tutorial: https://www.guru99.com/python-csv.html

Comment: Do you want the file to visually open? `open` returns a file descriptor.

Answer (score 1):

Your code returns the file descriptor, to view the csv file you have to open the file as you did but with a "with" statement like this:

```
with open(csvfile,'r')as f:
data = csv.reader(f)
for row in data:
    print(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just open the file using `csv.reader`, and start reading into it.

```py
>>> f = open(csvfile, "r")
>>> data = csv.reader(f)
>>> data
<_csv.reader object at 0x7f5a04e65208>
>>> for row in data:
        print(row)
```

If you are dealing in with CSV data, you can also use Pandas to make your life really easy. Here is an example:

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_csv(csvfile)
>>> df.head()
```